# AWS API Gateway with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have a Django Project deployed in AWS EC2 and have created all the REST APIs with DRF. Everything is working great. When I point `public.ip.of.ec2:8000/myapi`, I get the correct response and these APIs are used in Android application.

Now, day by day the API hits will be increased. So in order to maintain API requests I want to integrate my APIs with APIGateway. After a lot of reading and searching I still could not find any definitive tutorial or steps as of how to integrate APIGateway with EC2.

I've followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) but still could not integrate APIGateway with AWS Service i.e., EC2.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Django Project deployed in AWS EC2 and have created all the
>   REST APIs with DRF. Everything is working great. When I point
>   public.ip.of.ec2:8000/myapi, I get the correct response

Integration type you are looking for is [HTTP integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html)

> Now, day by day the API hits will be increased. So in order to
>   maintain API requests I want to integrate my APIs with APIGateway

Although you can configure API caching, throttling, logging and monitoring, AWS API Gateway won't scale your backend integration. You will need to configure autoscaling on backend service as well.